# Edit the format of date

Tags: python, pandas, python-dateutil

I try to convert the following format of date to another type:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
['09052022000000'],
['10052022000000'],
['11052022000000'],
['12052022000000'],
['13052022000000']],
columns=['Date'])

df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
print(df)
```

I want output to be like :

```
2022-05-09 00:00:00

2022-05-10 00:00:00

2022-05-11 00:00:00

2022-05-12 00:00:00

2022-05-13 00:00:00
```

But I get the following error :

````
result, tz_parsed = tslib.array_to_datetime(
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 381, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 613, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 751, in pandas._libs.tslib._array_to_datetime_object
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 742, in pandas._libs.tslib._array_to_datetime_object
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\parsing.pyx", line 281, in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string
  File "C:\Users\Mustafa_Jaber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 1368, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mustafa_Jaber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 651, 
in parse
    six.raise_from(ParserError(str(e) + ": %s", timestr), e)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: month must be in 1..12: 09052022000000
1```
````

Answer (score 1):

Use `format='%d%m%Y%H%M%S'` for `DDMMYYYYHHMMSS` format:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format='%d%m%Y%H%M%S')
print(df)
        Date
0 2022-05-09
1 2022-05-10
2 2022-05-11
3 2022-05-12
4 2022-05-13
```

because only times `00:00:00` are not displayed.

Check times if like need:

```
print(df["Date"].tolist())

[Timestamp('2022-05-09 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-05-10 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2022-05-11 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2022-05-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-05-13 00:00:00')]
```

EDIT: In real data are microseconds, so added `%f` to format and for convert wrong values to `NaT` (missing values) add parameter `errors='coerce'` :

```
L = [9052022000000000.0, 9052022000000000.0, 9052022000000000.0, 9052022001500000.0, 9052022001500000.0, 
     9052022001500000.0, 9052022003000000.0, 9052022003000000.0, 9052022003000000.0, 9052022004500000.0, 
     9052022004500000.0, 9052022004500000.0, 9052022010000000.0, 9052022010000000.0, 9052022010000000.0,
     9052022011500000.0, 9052022011500000.0, 9052022011500000.0, 9052022013000000.0, 9052022013000000.0]


df = pd.DataFrame({'dateTime':L})
df["dateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dateTime"], format='%d%m%Y%H%M%S%f', errors='coerce')
print(df)
              dateTime
0  2022-05-09 00:00:00
1  2022-05-09 00:00:00
2  2022-05-09 00:00:00
3  2022-05-09 00:15:00
4  2022-05-09 00:15:00
5  2022-05-09 00:15:00
6  2022-05-09 00:30:00
7  2022-05-09 00:30:00
8  2022-05-09 00:30:00
9  2022-05-09 00:45:00
10 2022-05-09 00:45:00
11 2022-05-09 00:45:00
12 2022-05-09 01:00:00
13 2022-05-09 01:00:00
14 2022-05-09 01:00:00
15 2022-05-09 01:15:00
16 2022-05-09 01:15:00
17 2022-05-09 01:15:00
18 2022-05-09 01:30:00
19 2022-05-09 01:30:00
```

If still last 3 values are `0` another idea is divide `1000`:

```
df["dateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dateTime"], format='%d%m%Y%H%M%S%f', errors='coerce')
```

Comment: oh, Thanks.
I do this like test but the main code is down, I think your solution does not work on the main code. I do not know.

Comment: `url = (
    "http://90.161.233.78:65519/services/user/records.xml?begin=09052022?end=10052022?var=EDSLINEEMBEDDED.Module2.VI1?var=EDSLINEEMBEDDED.Module2.API1?period=900"
)


df = pd.read_xml(url, xpath="//record/* | //dateTime")

df["dateTime"] = df["dateTime"].ffill()

df["dateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dateTime"], format='%d%m%Y%H%M%S')

df.dropna(inplace=True)

df.to_csv('output.csv')`

Comment: @MustafaJaber - Can you be more specific what means `solution does not work on the main code` ?

Comment: then code is above. it gives me an error.

Comment: @MustafaJaber - what is error?

Comment: `
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mustafa_Jaber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 510, in _to_datetime_with_format
    values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)

`

Comment: `
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 360, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'int'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mustafa_Jaber\Desktop\New folder\test.py", line 25, in <module>
    df["dateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dateTime"], format='%d%m%Y%H%M%S')
  File "C:\Users\Mustafa_Jaber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 1047, in to_datetime
  
`

Comment: `  cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
  File "C:\Users\Mustafa_Jaber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 197, in _maybe_cache
    cache_dates = convert_listlike(unique_dates, format)
  File "C:\Users\Mustafa_Jaber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 394, in 
`

Comment: @MustafaJaber - can you try `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format='%d%m%Y%H%M%S')` change to `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"].astype(str), format='%d%m%Y%H%M%S')`  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244605/discussion-between-mustafa-jaber-and-jezrael).